# SQL Server exception 'Must declare the scalar variable "@nameQuery".'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a practice SQL Server database project, and I'm trying to enter text into a SQL Server database through a Windows Form. I'm not sure if my text data was really entered to my database. How do I view if it was entered? I'm a beginner so please try to use beginner SQL and VS vocabulary. I've tried going to show table data but that shows that no data was entered so I'm assuming its not working. Whenever I hit the button it just gives me no response so I'm not sure.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DBHotel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Nicholas Hoffs\\source\\repos\\DBHotel\\DBHotel\\Hotel.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        private void instBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nameQuery = textInst.Text;

            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nameQuery, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers(name) VALUES(@nameQuery)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nameQuery", nameQuery);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you create your database? Whatever tool you used will also have functionality to examine the contents of your tables. And don't use [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is nonintuitive but try using the @ inside your AddWithValue:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameQuery", nameQuery);
```

Comment: jyelle , no it's great! I'm a beginner so I will take any advice, thanks!

Comment: You should consider moving your database code to a new class/file and putting it in a static function -- it's best practice to separate the code for the UI from the code for the DB logic. (Even though it might seem silly on a small project)

Comment: '@' is not required when populating a parameter value

Answer (score -2):

***EDIT: WARNING The below solution is at risk of sql injection, and is highly discouraged.***

As you are using direct query in instead of using stored procedure, you can't pass parameter to SQL. Instead of passing parameter try using

`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers(name) VALUES('" + nameQuery + "')";`

this means we are just concatenating the value of variable "nameQuery" in the query itself. so no need of below statement

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nameQuery", nameQuery);`

Comment: No don't try the first suggestion at all. That is at risk of sql injection.